# Datepicker string

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I've read the documentation and seen some materials on changing date format, however how do I work with strings in forms instead of `Date` objects?

I need to send to my backed form with date in specific format. Is there a setting I miss so I could get date string with desired format instead of `Date` object in FormGroup?

Comment: can you give some string date format and sample date format which you need to sent it to your backend?

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy Let's say I need `DD.MM.YY`

Comment: is it possible to use datepipe in your component?

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy I need to change the form value not the visible text.

Answer (score 0):

Imports :

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

DatePicker to Backend:

```
// example current date or specific
const datePicker = new FormControl(new Date() || '1980-01-01T00:00:00+01:00');

// Send to back with your specific format
const dateBack: string = moment(datePicker.value).format('DD.MM.YY');
```

Backend to DatePicker :

```
// example date recept from backend
const dateBack: string = '2020-03-12T00:00:00+01:00';

// convert date for datePicker
const datePicker: = new FormControl(dateBack);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try talking with the people responsible for the API - accepting dates as strings only instead of date objects is a bad practice to say the least.

If that's not possible, I'd say your best bet would be to convert it as late as possible not to bury that terrible logic in your components / services logic. Use [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to convert all the data in your outgoing requests. This solution will be good if you want to handle it globally for EVERY SINGLE outgoing request. An example interceptor (not tested - written out of my head) below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      body: this.dateToString(request.body)
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  dateToString(object: any): string {
    if (object === null || object === undefined) {
      return object;
    }

    if (typeof object !== 'object') {
      return object;
    }

    for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
      const value = object[key];
      if (value instanceof Date) {
        object[key] = this.formatDate(value);
      } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
        this.dateToString(value);
      }
    }
  }

  formatDate(date: Date): string {
    return date.toISOString();
  }
}    this.dateToString(value);
      }
    }
  }

  formatDate(date: Date): string {
    return date.toISOString();
  }
```

This needs to be registered in your module as well - see the linked docs.

I think recursive transformation of the request body, while not perfect performance wise, is pretty acceptable solution until they fix their API.

If you use more than one API, you can run a check if the request is for that particular API, e.g. by checking the request url:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('some-terrible-api')) {
      request = request.clone({
        body: this.dateToString(request.body)
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Of course, if you're using some other date providers (e.g. moment) you need to adjust your code accordingly, but the idea remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can use moment.js to convert date into any format you like.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

```
moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

using this you can convert date in a specific format as mentioned YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: U didn’t mentioned about that, next time mention your application size.

Answer (score -1):

You can import datepipe in your module.

```
`import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
.
.
.
providers: [DatePipe]`
```

And then you import datepipe in your constructor.

```
`import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
.
.
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

ngOnInit() {
  var date = new Date();
  console.log(this.datePipe.transform(date,"DD.MM.YY"));
}`
```

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zyx8d